# Distance from an arbitrary point to an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, optimization, least-squares, ellipsoids

I have a collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which I would like to fit an ellipsoid to. My approach is to frame it as an optimization problem, where for
$$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b} + \frac{(z-z_0)^2}{c} = 1 $$
I determine $a, b, c, x_0, y_0$ and $z_0$ such that the sum of the (squared) distance between my points and the ellipsoid is minimized. Here I have no previous knowledge regarding the center of the ellipse.

This all seems relatively simply to code up aside from determining the distance between each point to the ellipsoid. Does an analytic solution exist for this problem? If not, is there any other "nice" way of doing this?

Comment: Look up "Mahalanobis distance."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry I do not understand, how should I map my problem to one involving distributions?

Comment: If you have lots of data, you can use them to estimate a covariance matrix which fits an ellipsoid to the distribution of the data.  The distance from each point to the ellipsoid is the Mahalanobis distance.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Ah I see! And will this ellipsoid be described implicitly or will I have the center and parameters explicitly?

Comment: The mean of the ellipsoid is computed directly.  The eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix give the principal axes of the ellipsoid.